# how to make buildbot find the dynamic library in mac?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

I am using different machines to build and run project using buildbot. In linux the dynamic library is found ( I heard something about rpath) but in mac after I build and run. The binary that I use to run cant find dynamic library the binary needs. I could use export to say where the library is but I want some method to say mac machine where those library are. 
Can any one help me in this one, i tried setting

```
 env={"LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/local/lib"}
```

but no luck from there too.

**EDIT :**

what abarnert told was right. the only change I had to make was add DY in front of LD_LIBRARY_PATH so it will be (and also if you want to add more)

```
  env={"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/local/lib:/usr/where/is/lib"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is really what you want here, but if it is…

The equivalent for Darwin [`dyld`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html) (what OS X uses instead of the GNU `ldd` that Linux uses) is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Note that on OS X, you can link against frameworks as well as plain dynamic libraries. If you've done this, you will also probably need to set an additional variable, such as `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`.

Comment: thank you abarnert for the response .. but i have tried DYLD_LIBRART_PATH as well and results the same ( it work with export though)  .. I was doubting if the way I am setting env does necessarily helps finding the dynamic library. I mean whether its env job to do that or not :/